# Windows Embedded XP tskill and taskkill not recognized

Tags: windows, embedded, windows-xp

We have windows embedded xp machines, and we need to kill a process through the command line. The problem is that taskkill works on everything but the xp machines we have. we've tried tskill and taskkill, but both are not recognized on these xp machines.

Is there another way to kill a process from the command line in windows xp embedded machines other than tskill and taskkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XP Embedded is not a single standard OS; rather the developer embedding XP configures and tailors it to the needs of the target (usually single) application - omitting components not necessary to the target application.  As such it is probably not so much that XP Embedded does not have tskill, but rather than the developer chose to omit it.

In the end tskill is and executable file (tskill.exe), you could simply add it to your embedded platform from another XP system.

Comment: Its a good answer, so i'll give you credit for that, but i was hoping for another way to kill a process from the command line. in the end, i ended up writing a tiny exe which will do basically what taskkill would have done. our installer needs to kill the process, and instead of putting in taskkill.exe or something into the installer, since i'm not sure if thats even legal, it was just as fast to write a program myself to include in the installer

Comment: @iedoc : Yours is the better solution, but it is not an answer to the question you asked - it is perhaps an answer to the question you should have asked.  You should avoid [xy problem questions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem) - had you asked about your actual *problem*, rather than how to make *your solution* work, you'd probably have got the answer you eventually ended up at.  You are of course at liberty to post an answer to your own question - it may be of use or interest to others.

Comment: thanks @Clifford, but i don't think i can answer my question because what i really wanted to know is if there is any commands we can run from the command line to kill a process rather than tskill and taskkill

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/Q_27735459.html), and [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) may help too.  Google "xp embedded kill task" - that's what I did - it looks like you were right, it is not included in any XPe component after all.

Comment: Thanks @Clifford! Sadly, i've actually already come across PsKill, which is not included in windows xp

Comment: you know what? i'm going to mark this as the answer because it actually does answer my question. there seems to be no way to kill processes from the command line other than tskill, taskkill, and if you download it, pskill